# ideal diode wth a positive voltage?

Tags: diodes

I'm learning about the ideal diode.

The relation is pretty clear for V <= 0.

If V < 0, the diode blocks the current.

If V = 0, the current applied is the current out, and it needs to be controlled with a resistance to make sure the diode doesn't break.

However, I cannot find a clear explanation about what happens when V > 0? In most document I find, they don't even mention it! Would it be impossible?

Comment: It's an ideal diode with zero forward volt drop therefore V cannot be greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!! English not being my first langage, I'm unsure by what you mean by "zero forward volt drop"?

Comment: V cannot rise above 0 because it is a perfect diode - for it to be above zero would imply infinite current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic model of a diode says that no matter how much current is going through it in the forward direction, the voltage is 0. So the voltage can never be greater than 0 because that would require a "more than infinite" amount of current, which can't be produced by any source.

A more accurate model for a pn-junction diode is given by the Shockley diode equation

$$I = I_s \left(e^{\frac{qV}{nk_BT}}-1\right)$$

With this model you can predict the behavior for positive forward voltages, however if the voltage exceeds what we usually take as the turn-on voltage of the diode (often around 0.7 V), we will find that a very large current is produced (10's, 100's, 100's of A, or more). In the real world, forcing a high enough voltage will lead to burning out the diode.